# Edit an existing SQL view in GeoServer instead of creating a new one

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, geoserver-manager

There is a really solid guide to creating new views

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

But I can't find anything on changing the underlying SQL that populates an existing GeoServer view. We have a use case where we would like to change SQL that gets an existing data layer, potentially adding parameters and the like. Is that possible? Or should we build the layer from scratch?

Comment: do you mean a view you created in GeoServer or an arbitrary one that GeoServer knows nothing about?

Comment: I would like to edit an existing view that I created in GeoServer

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the SQL that makes up the layer by clicking on the `edit sql view` link at the bottom of the `Edit Layer` page's `Data` tab.

[image]

Comment: Welll derp, dont know how I missed that but thanks!

Comment: Cant actually see that link, might be a permissions issue Ill look into that

Comment: what version are you using? that's been there for more than 2 years

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem that "Edit sql view" link is missing. I am using 2.23.2 GeoServer version. Therefore, I can't edit existing SQL view. Is there any other way to do that in this version?

Comment: I think the only other reason that link would be missing would be that the layer is not based on a view